# How to create Orika global Object Factory?

Tags: java, spring, orika

Is there any way to create a global object factory? I mean, for example:

```
this.mapper.map(source, MyClass.class);
this.mapper.map(source, MyClass2.class);
```

I want that when orika creates MyClass and MyClass2 instance then do it through custom object factory, but not just for this classes, i want this for each one.

Is there some generic way to accomplish this? The reason for this is because i am using Spring and i want that my custom Object Factory add instances to the ApplicationContext when it creates one.

Comment: Wonder if OP ever figured out an answer. I am currently trying to puzzle how to build an ObjectFactoryFactory of sorts, so that it can automatically construct and register object factories for a bunch of classes